# How to close HTTP/2 client stream when server closes request stream?

Tags: go, http2

Created a HTTP/2 client and server program using net/http Go library for streaming client and server request response. Taken the reference from code here https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13444#issuecomment-161115822 .

Server code

```
func handle_stream_request(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    i := 0
    for {
        i = i + 1
        if i == 10 {
            break
        }
        len, _ := r.Body.Read(buf)
        response_str := "Server ACK for: " + string(buf[:len])
        w.Write([]byte(response_str))
        if f, ok := w.(http.Flusher); ok {
            f.Flush()
        }
    }
}
```

Client Code

```
func send_stream_request(client *http.Client) {
    pr, pw := io.Pipe()
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("PUT", "https://localhost:8000/", ioutil.NopCloser(pr))
    var res *http.Response

    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
            s := "Client ping@" + get_time()
            pw.Write([]byte(s))
            if res != nil {
                buf := make([]byte, 1024)
                len, _ := res.Body.Read(buf)
                log.Printf("Response is: %s", string(buf[:len]))
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        response, _ := client.Do(req)
        res = response
        log.Printf("\n Got: %#v", res)
    }()
    select {}
}
```

**What did you expect to see?**

After 10 requests from client the client program should exit successfully.

**What did you see instead?**

The client program blocks at writing at pipe "pw.Write([]byte(s))" after server has finished the handle function because there is no reader to read the data on pipe.

I am not able to understand how can I stop such client program from hanging. What signal does server send to client that request stream has been closed and it shouldn't try to write more stuff on pipe.